# Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, jboss7.x

I upgraded my jackson libraries from 2.5.4 to 2.10.1 as you'll see below and I receive the following error:

```
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"m2m-rt.ear\".\"app.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"app.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"app.jar\" of deployment \"app.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class Class with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.app.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Class.<init>()V @19: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'
```

With my own research, I am finding that it should be rather simple to exclude the jackson libraries in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.picketbox"/>
            <module name="org.wildfly.clustering.singleton"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF" />
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf" />
                    <include path="META-INF/services" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="other.jar">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.infinispan" slot="5.2"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I also tried including this in my jboss deployment structure instead of doing the exclusions at the root level:

```
<sub-deployment name="firstJar.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
```

Here is how I define my jackson libraries in my gradle build script. These libraries are part of a jar that gets deployed with a few other jars and a war into an ear. Four of the other jar modules are dependent on the jar that includes the jackson libraries

Part of my firstJar:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.1'
```

A gradle build script of another jar that depends on the one above:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':components:firstJar')
}
```

Using JBoss EAP 7.0.5

One thing I noticed when I ran a gradle dependency scan is with the 2.5.4 version jackson libraries my scan looks like this:

```
    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.5.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.0
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.5.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.5.4
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4 (*)
```

And when I run it for 2.10.1 it looks like this:

```
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4 -> 2.10.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.1
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.1
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1 (*)
```

I noticed there's an extra `jackson-annotations` dependency for 2.10.1. So I tried adding `exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'` for the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` library in my gradle script, which does remove it from the dependency scan. But I am still left with the same errors. I'm also wondering why in first line of the dependency scan for 2.10.1, it says `2.5.4 -> 2.10.1`.

Comment: This generally means that libraries are loaded multiple times from different classpath hierarchies.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes. The problem for me is how can I get some of them excluded like I've been trying.

Comment: @Drew13 any ideas on this? I'm facing the same exact problem like you and I don't find any solution

Comment: @GeorgeFandango I ended up finding a solution. I will post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up needing to exclude the `jackson` and `resteasy` libraries in multiple modules (jars) as well as at the root level in my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. The modules that I am specifying to exclude the libraries use the module that imports the libraries (i.e. where in my question I state `A gradle build script of another jar that depends on the one above:`).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.picketbox"/>
            <module name="org.wildfly.clustering.singleton"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF" />
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf" />
                    <include path="META-INF/services" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="moduleThatDependsOnFirst.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="anotherModuleThatDependsOnFirst.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

One thing that I don't understand is why I didn't need to exclude the libraries for other jars that use the module that imports the libraries.
So a suggestion I would have for others having issues with this is to play around with which jars you exclude the libraries from in order to get this to work.